Verifying Email Validation Status with Firebase Authentication in Google Cloud API Gateway
I'm currently working on a project where I need to verify that users accessing my API have validated their email addresses using Firebase Authentication. I'm using Google Cloud API Gateway to manage API requests, and I want to ensure that only users with validated email addresses can access certain endpoints.
Is this possible?
